# How can I select all parameters to run a report, but have them run independently

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My quality engineers have asked me to create a report based on a document that they fill out manually.  At first glance, it appeared to be an easy enough request.  It has been anything but easy. This report shows the results of two inspections and I have a parameter where the user selects one inspection or the other.  As it stands now, this report runs just fine when selecting one inspection, but I am anticipating a request to be able to run the reports for both inspections at the same time.  And, that's where I run into trouble.

The problem is that I have a text box in the header that is referencing a value from a table in the report that identifies the inspection.  When I set the parameter to a multi-value parameter and select all, the report only displays one of the inspections across the entire report.  Is it possible to have the user select both inspections but have the report run them separately?  I have one dataset for the table and a column in that table that identifies the inspection.  I have tried the multi-value parameter and I have tried using the filter option in the dataset properties, but I get the same result.

[image: Inspection Report]

Comment: Your question is really unclear, I am struggling to make sense of it. I don't know if this is what you are asking, but normally when you have a multi-valued parameter, you display the selected parameter label(s) on the report, not the value from the dataset. So if you allow you users to select "Option 1", or "Option 2" or both, you write some logic to display the labels of the parameter values selected. But some clarifying details would really help for this question.

Comment: I my query, I have a parameter for the inspection in the WHERE clause.  So, when the user selects an inspection it will pull that data.  If the user selects XRAY, "XRAY" will be displayed under the title.  Likewise, if they select NEUTRON.  As I mentioned, if you select one inspection or the other, it will be displayed correctly under the title.  But, if you select both inspections, only one will display under the title for the entire report despite which inspection data is being displayed. - David

Comment: As I said, use the parameter labels for the title.

Comment: Presumably your datasource will return multiple rows per "inspection". Equally, each inspection consists of multiple rows. So you now need to use grouping in the report. Also presumably you want each inspection to start on a new page when printing (and perhaps for display purposes as well).

Comment: I've added an answer but after reading the comments, if your only problem is showing both parameter labels then you can use some thing like `=JOIN(Parameters!Inspection.Label, " ")`

Comment: The List control allows you to repeat sections of a report based on a grouping criteria. So you add the list, and tell it what to group in, then you add your report components inside the list and they will display the data filtered by what the list row is currently showing. So this would allow you to repeat as much or little of your report per "inspection" as you require.

Comment: I agree with @DaleK. Use a list grouped by inspection and embed the entire report in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this might be to create a new master report and use your current report as a sub-report. It's fairly simple.

Here's the basic steps...

Make a copy of your current report and rename it (say `sub_InspectionReport`)
Change this report so the the inspection parameter is **NOT** multi-valued

Create a new report and add your parameter(s) the same as you setup for your original report, This time make sure your Inspection parameter (e.g. `pInspection`)  **IS** multi-valued.

Create a dataset (`dsInspectionIDs`) that returns a list of the selected inspection values from the `pInspection` parameter. The query could be something simple like

```
SELECT InspectionID FROM myInspectionTable WHERE InpectionID IN (@pInspection)
```

**Note:** `@pInspection` is the name of your report parameter, it is case sensitive.

Now add a table to the report and, as a simple, test, se the dataset of the table to your daatset `dsInspectionIDs`. Set the first column to show the only available field (in this example `InspectionID`).

Run the report and test the output using different inspection parameter selections. The table should match what you have selected...

We're almost there...

Now in one of the table cells (but not in the header) , right-click and select "Insert  / Subreport". Now right-click the sub-report placeholder and set the sub report to be the copy of the original report we made at the start (`sub_InspectionReport` in this example).  Now, still in the sub-report properties,  go to the parameters tab and set the Inspection parameter to the the InspectionID field.

Now when you run the report, you will get your sub-report run once for each selected parameter value with that parameter passed to the sub-report.

Hope that makes sense, I'm not near my PC so I can't provide a sample with images at the moment.

Comment: I couldn't get the subreport to work, but I think that has to do with my access, or lack thereof, to the report server.  IT still hasn't granted me access.  I also tried using a list, but it also did the same thing where it would only display one inspection for the entire report.  I appreciate your help on this, but I think I will leave the report as-is and tell the engineers that they will have to select the inspections individually.